# How can I optimize this switch statement?

Tags: javascript, optimization

I try to use in my app, simple comparator to filter some data with passing  string filter instead  function as eg. passed to `[].filter` 
 Comparator should return function which will be a filter.

```
   var comparator = function( a, b, c ) { 
        switch( b ){
            case '>=': return function() { return this[a] >= c;}; break;
            case '<=': return function() { return this[a] <= c;}; break;
            case '<':  return function() { return this[a] < c;}; break;
            case '>':  return function() { return this[a] > c;}; break;
            case '=':  return function() { return this[a] == c;}; break;
            case '==': return function() { return this[a] === c;}; break;
            case '!=': return function() { return this[a] != c;}; break;
            default: return null;
        };

    }
```

Assume that i get this function by:

```
  var filterFn = comparator.apply({}, /(.+)(=|>=|<=|<|>|!=|==|!==)(.+)/.exec( "id<4" ).slice(1) );


  someModel = someModel.objects.filter( filterFn );
```

The target it will look:

```
   someModel.get = function( filter ){ 
      return new Model(  
           this.objects.filter(
               comparator.apply({}, /(.+)(=|>=|<=|<|>|!=|==|!==)(.+)/.exec( "id<4" ).slice(1) 
           ) 
      );
   };
   var filtered = someModel.get( "id<4" );
```

**Question is - I assume that it will be a lot more operators and I have no idea how to write it  more simply.**

**Using Eval is out of question.**

This code didn't was both executed and tested  I wrote it just to show what I mean.

Comment: Is `eval()` out of the question even if you compare the operator `c` against an array of known, whitelisted possible values?

Comment: Are you going to need a full expression parser, e.g. no only single operators?

Comment: Note that you don't need `break` statements after each `return`.

Comment: @nnnnnn I know that.
It irritates me that I must rewrite the operators in an expression as well as additional switch list to. Although probably will not be able to do it otherwise.

Comment: Hint from @Michael gives some food for thought...

Comment: What's the problem? Aside from the `break`s being redundant, your `switch` looks fine.

Comment: The question is not clear. What is the input, what is the expected output?  What is the purpose of all this?  Why not do this inline?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Store every function in an object, either pre-defined, or dynamically.

If you want to dyanmically create the set of functions, define the `comparator` object as shown below. I assumed that you did not extend the `Object.prototype`. If you did, `operators.hasOwnProperty(property)` has to be used within the first loop.

```
// Run only once
var funcs = {};   // Optionally, remove `funcs` and swap `funcs` with `operators`
var operators = { // at the first loop.
    '>=': '>=',
    '<=': '<=',
    '<' :  '<',
    '>' :  '>',
    '=' : '==', //!!
    '==':'===', //!!
    '!=': '!='
}; // Operators

// Function constructor used only once, for construction
for (var operator in operators) {
    funcs[operator] = Function('a', 'c',
                       'return function() {return this[a] ' + operator + ' c};');
}

// Run later
var comparator = function(a, b, c) {
    return typeof funcs[b] === 'function' ? funcs[b](a, c) : null;
};
```

When `comparator` is invoked, the returned function looks like:

```
function() {  return this[a] < c;   }// Where a, c are pre-determined.
```

This method can be implemented in this way (**[demo at JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KWEUd/)**):

```
// Assumed that funcs has been defined
function implementComparator(set, key, operator, value) {
    var comparator, newset = [], i;

    if (typeof funcs[operator] === 'function') {
        comparator = funcs[operator](key, value);
    } else { //If the function does not exist...
        throw TypeError("Unrecognised operator");
    }

    // Walk through the whole set
    for (i = 0; i < set.length; i++) {
        //  Invoke the comparator, setting `this` to `set[i]`. If true, push item
        if (comparator.call(set[i])) {
            newset.push(set[i]);
        }
    }
    return newset;
}
var set = [ {meow: 5}, {meow: 3}, {meow: 4}, {meow: 0}, {meow: 9}]
implementComparator( set , 'meow', '<=', 5);
// equals: [ {meow: 5}, {meow: 3}, {meow: 4}, {meow: 0} ]
```

For clarification, I constructed this answer, while keeping the following in mind:

- The OP requests an simple, easily extensible method with an unknown/dynamic set of operators.
- The code is based on the pseudo-code at the OP, without changing anything which could affect the intent of the OP. With some adjustments, this function can also be used for [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) or [`Array.prototype.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).
- `eval` (or `Function`) should not be used at every call to `comparator`

Comment: I totally forgot about creating a function from a string:) Thanks.

Comment: @abuduba Are you sure about `==`, `===` and `!=`? Your code doesn't implement a negated identity **`!==`** operator. Also, use another RegExp if you want to implement a solid calculator. Currently, your pattern will select **any** character: `(.+)` Does **also** select the operators, if existent.

Comment: This is basically the same as using `eval`. Just because you don't use the exact function name doesn't mean you're not creating code from a string then running it. Would `function not_eval(str) { return eval(str); }` also be acceptable?

Comment: @Rob W: isn't `Function(...)` `eval` in disguise?

Comment: `Function` is not more efficient than `eval`. Use closures instead. You actually do not need two `Object`s. And be sure to use `hasOwnProperty()` with `for..in`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit If they were used directly, then yes, they would be same. But notice *how* I use the `Function` constructor. I create a function which accepts two parameters. No matter how often the `comparator` is executed, the number of `Function` (~= `eval`) executions is always the same. Your suggestion of `eval` has to be run every time, and will cause **memory leaks**, because the code is unable to garbage-collect.

Comment: In the question I wrote  - My code didn't was both executed and tested I wrote it just to show what I mean. I was about  wonder how to do that , now I will   wonder about the operators which will be needed .

Comment: @RobW: I wasn't actually _suggesting_ it ;) Merely pointing out that, in my view, this answer is covered under what the OP _didn't_ want to do (though he doesn't seem to realise that yet!)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit and @Kooilnc - The point was to avoid using `eval` on the values passed to `comparator(a,b,c)`. Rob's answer only uses the `Function()` equivalent of `eval` to create the various comparator functions in the first place. Those functions, once created, are the equivalent of the functions in the question and do not use `eval`...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The OP avoids `eval` because, hey, "eval is evil" is a common phrase. The reasons for this are mainly speed and memory leaks. My solution does not suffer from these, as explained at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: @RobW: I thought the popular reason was that it does not inherently employ a failsafe approach to security, in an inherently security-issue-prone feature. But what the hey!

Comment: @RobW You are not returning a comparator. You are returning the result of a compare operation. The only merit of your solution is that you are compiling the functions in a loop. And ISTM the OP, being confused right from the start, accepted this because it *looks* cool (but is really very inefficient and error-prone).

Comment: Sorry, but I do not think the OP is aware that this is a *bad idea* in the first place. For this is *not* how you build a *reusable* comparator. And as for the memory leaks issue, where is your *evidence*? For example, in ES5 Strict Mode, the scope chain of `eval` code is *empty*.

Comment: Your example that should prove `eval()` differs from `Function()` with regard to garbage collection is bogus.  **Objects** *can* be garbage-collected if they are no longer referred.  Objects are *not* involved here. `y` is not referred from within the function. What you might *mean* is that the Variable Object of which `y` is a property *might* not be garbage-collected because it is referred through the scope chain of `eval` code. But not in Strict Mode. And your code does *not* "literally translate the pseudo-code" because you forgot `this`. And you need a **closure** to consider it.

Comment: Revised answer, removed garbage (ty), added explanation + demo: http://jsfiddle.net/KWEUd/

Comment: Much better now. But: 1. It is wrong that you need `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty()` with `for..in` only if you augment `Object.prototype` yourself. The ECMAScript implementation may have built-in enumerable properties on the prototype object. But more efficient in implementations of ES5 is a one-time call of `Object.keys(operators)` and then `for`-iterating over the resulting `Array`. 2. The `typeof` operation considers the prototype chain as well, so you would need `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty()` there, too, unless you want to support other methods that act as an operator.

Comment: Supplemental: As you can see, the token `set` has special meaning, and may become a reserved word; avoid it for identifiers. (Same for `get`.)

Comment: @PointedEars 1. `Object.keys` is shorter, but is not supported in FF 3.6-, IE8-. These browsers are still [widely used](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Firefox_usage_share). I assumed that the code has to support as much browsers as possible (usually a good guess at SO). My code assumed that `Object.prototype` has not been modified, and the examples are based on that. Small note at the top in case one decides to modify  Objects prototype. 3. As for `get` and `set`, I [cannot find a source for your statement that these are (future) reserved words](http://es5.github.com/#x7.6.1).

Comment: 1. This concerns *efficiency*, not length. `if (typeof Object.keys == "function") { var keys = Object.keys(operators); for (var i = keys.length; i--;) { var operator = keys[i]; funcs[operator] = …; } } else { for (…) { if (operators.hasOwnProperty(…)) { … } } }`. As for `Object.prototype`: man *built-in*. 3. I did *not* say they *are* reserved words, only that they are *special*: [Defining getters and setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters).

Answer (score 2):

Don't do it so dynamically....it would be far more efficient to only create the functions once, rather than each time they are called, as that would create a new funciton and so a memory leak each time the compare is done.

```
var comparator = {
    ">=":  function(a, b) { return a >= b;},    
    "<=":  function(a, b) { return a <= b;},
    "add": function(a, b) { return a + b; },

compare: function(typeString, a, b){
    if(comparator.hasOwnProperty(typeString) == true){

        var theFunction = comparator[typeString];

        return theFunction(a, b);   
    }
    else{
        alert("typeString '" + typeString + "' not supported.");
     }
}, };

var test = comparator.compare(">=", 5, 4);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var comparator = (function () {
  var fns = {
    '>=': function (a, c) { return a >= c; },
    '<=': function (a, c) { return a <= c; },
    '<':  function (a, c) { return a < c; },
    '>':  function (a, c) { return a > c; },
    '=':  function (a, c) { return a == c; },
    '==': function (a, c) { return a === c; },
    '!=': function (a, c) { return a != c; }
  };

  return function (b) { 
    return fns.hasOwnProperty(b) ? fns[b] : null;
  };
}());
```

At this point you can see that nothing is more efficient than an inline expression. It is not clear to me why you think you need to be so dynamic beforehand.

Comment: Well, I could not see the original code making a lot of sense (operands *and* operator are in a closure – why not do this inline instead?), so I posted a solution that does make sense to me (fixed operator, variable operands).